# Python pandas - stylize/highlight a row based on the value of 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to highlight the row if there is empty data in any of the 2 columns (either row2/row3 or both), so that i can see it easier.

for example:

```
col1 col2 col3
a    23    16
b          12
c    12
d
```

the return result should be the rows b,c,d highlighted in yellow. any idea how to achieve this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use custom function:

```
def highlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: yellow'

    # condition
    m = x.isna().any(axis=1)
    #if need specify columns for check
    m = x[['col2','col3']].isna().any(axis=1)
    #print (m)
    #empty DataFrame of styles
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    #set new columns by condition
    return df1.mask(m, c1)


df.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```